# What does the autotest autoupdate module do?

Tags: ruby, autotest, zentest

https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/blob/master/lib/autotest/autoupdate.rb

It's not documented and I can't find any discussion about it on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs the `@@update_cmd` (by default: `svn up`) every `@@sleep_time` seconds (by default: `60`).

Comment: `svn` as in subversion? That's old school!

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: You can set it to whatever you like.